# Unusual datetime string parsing in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hi I am trying to parse the following string in hive

```
"2016-09-30T21:59:58.093Z"
```

I would like to extract the year, month, day and hour from it. 
I can use the year(), day() and to_date() function to extract up to the day, but I can't get the hour from it. If I do

```
hour("2016-09-30T21:59:58.093Z")
```

or

```
unix_timestamp("2016-09-30T21:59:58.093Z")
```

they will return NULL. Can someone suggest something? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2016-09-30T21:59:58.093Z","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH");
OK
2016-09-30 21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translate("2016-09-30T21:59:58.093Z", "T"," ")` for the output